# Why can't I have both @Input and @HostBinding in my angular component that uses Reactive Forms?

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I have an issue where I'm seeing only one of either @Input or @HostBinding display, but not both.
What I want

[image]

If I have the following, the label displays fine as seen in this screenshot with only the label and no data below it yet (which is fine because that part wasn't added yet)

[image]

```
<label-and-item label="Item Type"></label-and-item>
```

and the component

```
export class ItemAndLabelComponent {
  @Input() label: string;
}
```

with html

```
<label>{{label}}</label>
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

---

But once I add @Hostbinding as shown below, I do see the bound data as was intended, but now the label is missing.

[image]

```
<label-and-item label="Item Type" controlName="sType"></label-and-item>

export class ItemAndLabelComponent {
  @Input() label: string;
  @Input() controlName: string;

  constructor(@Optional() private parent: ControlContainer) {}

  @HostBinding('textContent')
  get controlValue() {
    return this.parent ? this.parent.control.get(this.controlName).value : '';
  }
}

<label>{{label}}</label>
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

I'm using @Hostbinding because I wanted get the form data that matches the form control name on a simple element. I did not want to have to use input, select, textarea or anything that has "value" property and thus I could not use formControlName.
Any thoughts on what could be causing this are much appreciated.

Comment: What is the issue are you getting any error?

Comment: No errors showing in console or anywhere. I updated with screenshots to make a bit clearer.